# How to install an Adobe app from another Mac using Remote Disc?

Tags: mac, install, remote-control

I recently deleted some Adobe files & now when I try to reinstall Photoshop Elements I get the error message: "installer failed to initialize."

Adobe is no help at all.

I can't restore the files I deleted (not even sure which missing files are needed), so the Adobe installer won't work at all.

I'm told I can use Remote Disc to use my Macbook Pro to install it on my Mac Mini. Or maybe use Migration Assistant to transfer Elements from my Macbook Pro to the Mini.

How does this work? Suggestions?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

First, on the machine with the optical drive, go to System Preferences > Sharing and make sure "DVD & CD Sharing" is turned on.

Then, on the machine without the optical drive (the one where you want to install the software), open a Finder window and select "Remote Disc" in the sidebar (if you don't see it, go to Finder > Preferences > Sidebar and make sure "CDs, DVDs, and iPods" is checked under the Devices category). You can also navigate to root (`/`) and you'll see it there too.

Provided the two machines are on the same wifi network, Remote Disc will show the contents of the optical disc in the other machine, and from there you can run the installer or do whatever you need to do.